# Use dplyr::mutate and lubridate::force_tz based on arguments from data frame columns

Tags: r, timezone, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to use lubridate::force_tz to add timezone information to timestamps (date+time) formatted as strings (as.character()). Both are stored as two columns in a data frame:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
row1<-c(as.character(now()),"Etc/UTC")
row2<-c(as.character(now()+5),"America/Chicago")
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(row1,row2))
names(df)<-c("dt","tz")

x<-force_tz(as.POSIXct(as.character(now())),"Etc/UTC") #works
df<-df%>%mutate(newDT=force_tz(as.POSIXct(dt),tz)) #fails
```

I get: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Following Stibu's comments, I tried (an un-R like) approach with an iteration:

```
for (i in seq(from=1,to=length(df$dt))){
timestamp<-as.character(df[i,1])
tz<-as.character(df[i,2])
print(tz)
newdt<-force_tz(as.POSIXct(timestamp),tz)
df[i,3]<-newdt
print(attr(df[i,3],"tzone"))
df$timezone<-attr(df[i,3],"tzone")
}
```

This extracts the values correctly, but seems to get stuck with setting the value of the tz to the first value encountered - weirdly:

```
[1] "Etc/UTC"
[1] "Etc/UTC"
[1] "America/Chicago"
[1] "Etc/UTC"
```

I would have expected the last printout to result in `"America/Chicago"`
The df then looks like:

```
 > df
               dt              tz               newDT timezone
 1 2016-04-13 23:07:45         Etc/UTC 2016-04-13 23:07:45  Etc/UTC
 2 2016-04-13 23:07:50 America/Chicago 2016-04-14 04:07:50  Etc/UTC
```

Comment: Stibu below provided a nice explanation, highlighting two issues - one is with my replicable example (I will edit the question once I get time), the second is the real culprit ( I have diagnosed the issue as the same but could not believe that I cannot pass an element from a vector to tz=.... Others, please look at that part of the answer of Stibu if you can help me...

Comment: I have found a related post here, but I was not able to make it run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848563/with-tz-with-a-vector-of-timezones/33848764#33848764

Comment: And there is a thread with other people discussin on lubridate github: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598115/use-dplyrmutate-and-lubridateforce-tz-based-on-arguments-from-data-frame-col

Answer (score 2):

You have actually two issues in your code that I will discuss separately below.

### dplyr works with data frames

Your `df` is a matrix, not a data frame. But `mutate()` (and functions from dplyr in general) works with data frames. The error message simply tells you that `mutate()` does not know what to do with a matrix.

You can solve this by converting `df` to a data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df)<-c("dt","tz")
```

A remark regarding `names()`: This function can be used to get/set the column names of a data frame. For matrices, the corresponding function is `colnames()`. You used `names()` on a matrix, which did **not** set the column names of the matrix. Therefore, the names of the data frame are also not set after conversion.

You could also create a data frame from the start as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(dt = as.character(c(now(), now() + 5)),
                 tz = c("Etc/UTC", "America/Chicago"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note that you need to define the contents column-wise, not row-wise as you did.

If you use the data frame `df`, there will be no error from `mutate()`.

### One time zone per vector

Unfortunately, there is a second issue. What you want to do  simply  cannot be done. The reason is the following.

Let's convert the first column of `df` to `POSIXct` with time zone `CET`:

```
ts <- as.POSIXct(df$dt, tz = "CET")
ts
## [1] "2016-04-13 14:42:26 CEST" "2016-04-13 14:42:31 CEST"
```

Let's try to do the same with two time zones:

```
ts <- as.POSIXct(df$dt, tz = c("CET", "UTC"))
## Error in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) : 
##   invalid 'tz' value
```

This does not work. The reason is that there is a *single time zone per vector* and not a time zone per element in the vector. Look at the attributes of `ts`:

```
attributes(ts)
## $class
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
## 
## $tzone
## [1] "CET"
```

The time zone is set as an attribute of the entire vector and it is not a property of each element.

Comment: Thank you Stibu for a nice and extensive explanation. I appreciate the comments about the df (and meas culpa, this happened while producing a replicable example). My real dataset is a df properly. SO the second part of the answer is the key. Can you think of an approach that would help here?  I thought that maybe a traditional loop, but it felt very un-R... I would accept also any other answer that allows to use a "lookup" df/table to set tz to numerous records. Otherwise I resort to a db I guess...

Comment: Whether you use a loop or not, you will not be able to store all the time stamps in a single vector. You could produce a list with lapply. But I think that the right approach for you depends on what you want to do in the end.

Comment: HI Stibu, not sure I understand how a list would be different to a vector. What I want is to have a column in a df with all timestamps pegged to their respective timezones, so that I can do arithmetics with timestamps reliably ( difference of two instants in different timezones resulting in proper interval lengths).

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect our discussion, thanks!

Comment: Regarding your edit: nothing is weird there. As I tried to explain, a POSIXct vector has a single time zone. When you store the first time stamp in `df$newDT`, the time zone is set to `"Etc/UTC"`. And it does not change when you store the next element in `df$newDT`. Rather that time stamp is converted to `"Etc/UTC"`. If you are interested in the time differences, this is exactly what you need. The list would help, because each list element could be a POSIXct-vector of length one with its own time zone.

Comment: Thanks Stibu. The situation is that I have 5 columns with timestamps. Each timestamp may be in a different timezone. I am computing differences within rows, across columns. Each row is for tracking one item... I will have to take the timestamps without timezones, and the timezone information, and somehow imprint the timezone on the timestamp, and convert to UTC> then I will have UTC timestamps across the DF, which would be fine ( and I think it would also help with the daylight savings problems).