# Convert vector with local times to UTC

Tags: r, time

I have a `POSIXct` vector that slightly misuses that format:

```
> head(df$datetime)
[1] "2016-03-03 12:30:00 UTC" "2016-03-03 12:00:00 UTC" "2016-02-27 09:00:00 UTC" "2016-03-03 17:30:00 UTC"
[5] "2016-03-03 10:30:00 UTC" "2016-03-03 14:30:00 UTC"
```

These datetimes are marked as being UTC times but are really in an assortment of local timezones:

```
> df %>% select(datetime, timezone) %>% head
         datetime            timezone
1 2016-03-03 12:30:00 Australia/Melbourne
2 2016-03-03 12:00:00 Europe/Berlin
3 2016-02-27 09:00:00 Europe/Amsterdam
4 2016-03-03 17:30:00 Australia/Brisbane
5 2016-03-03 10:30:00 Europe/Amsterdam
6 2016-03-03 14:30:00 Europe/Berlin
```

I would like to convert these datetimes to UTC proper – in some sense the inverse problem faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848563/with-tz-with-a-vector-of-timezones) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848563/with-tz-with-a-vector-of-timezones) – but am having a hard time. A variation of the solution from the second link works:

```
get_utc_time <- function(timestamp_local, local_tz) {
  l <- lapply(seq(length(timestamp_local)), 
              function(x) {with_tz(force_tz(timestamp_local[x], tzone=local_tz[x]), tzone='UTC')})
  as.POSIXct(combine(l), origin = '1970-01-01 00:00.00', tz = 'UTC')
}

df$datetime_utc <- get_utc_time(df$datetime, df$timezone)
```

(`dplyr::mutate(df, datetime_utc = get_utc_time(datetime, timezone))`, which I thought would be equivalent, throws an error.)

But since this isn't vectorized, it's terribly slow on a data.frame with half a million rows. Is there a more elegant and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most 'official' way I know involves formatting and reparsing; David Smith [had a post on this a while ago](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html) on the REvolutions blog.

Time series libraries, particularly those which are timezone-aware, can do it too.  Here is an approach using RcppCCTZ which is my wrapper around CCTZ (written by some Googler's but not an official Google library) -- it computes the difference (by default in hours) between two timezones.

```
library(RcppCCTZ)  # you need the GitHub version though

# your data
df <- read.csv(text="datetime,timezone
2016-03-03 12:30:00,Australia/Melbourne
2016-03-03 12:00:00,Europe/Berlin
2016-02-27 09:00:00,Europe/Amsterdam
2016-03-03 17:30:00,Australia/Brisbane
2016-03-03 10:30:00,Europe/Amsterdam
2016-03-03 14:30:00,Europe/Berlin", stringsAsFactor=FALSE)

# parse to POSIXct
df[,"pt"] <- as.POSIXct(df[,"datetime"])

# compute difference
for (i in 1:6) 
    df[i,"diff"] <- tzDiff("UTC", df[i,"timezone"], df[i,"pt"])
```

This gets us this data.frame:

```
R> df
             datetime            timezone                  pt diff
1 2016-03-03 12:30:00 Australia/Melbourne 2016-03-03 12:30:00   11
2 2016-03-03 12:00:00       Europe/Berlin 2016-03-03 12:00:00    1
3 2016-02-27 09:00:00    Europe/Amsterdam 2016-02-27 09:00:00    1
4 2016-03-03 17:30:00  Australia/Brisbane 2016-03-03 17:30:00   10
5 2016-03-03 10:30:00    Europe/Amsterdam 2016-03-03 10:30:00    1
6 2016-03-03 14:30:00       Europe/Berlin 2016-03-03 14:30:00    1
R>
```

It would be simple to return the parsed Datetime offset as well,
but the little helper function [tzDiff](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcctz/blob/master/src/utilities.cpp#L8-L60) is not currently doing this.  I could add that as a second helper function if you want to go this route...

*Edit:*  This is an interesting problem. I have by now added some code to RcppCCTZ to do this, but it is not (yet, at least) vectorized.  That said, we can have a IMHO much simpler *and faster* solution using data.table.

Let's first encode your solution and the three packages it needs:

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
useLubridate <- function(df) {
    df %>%
        group_by(timezone) %>%
        mutate(datetime_local = ymd_hms(datetime, tz=unique(timezone))) %>%
        mutate(datetime_utc = with_tz(datetime_local, tzone = 'UTC')) %>% 
        ungroup %>%
        select(datetime_local) -> df
    df
}
```

The let's do the same for data.table:

```
library(data.table)
useDataTable <- function(df) {
    dt <- as.data.table(df)
    dt[, pt := as.POSIXct(datetime, tz=timezone[1]), by=timezone] 
    dt[]
}
```

Note that this returns three columns rather than just one.

And while we're at it, let's do a horse race:

```
R> library(microbenchmark)
R> microbenchmark( useDataTable(df), useLubridate(df) )
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval cld
 useDataTable(df) 1.23148 1.53900 1.61174 1.57635 1.64734  3.85423   100  a 
 useLubridate(df) 7.51158 8.88734 9.10439 9.19390 9.38032 15.27572   100   b
R>
```

So data.table is faster while also returning more useful information.  Collating the third column back into a data.frame (or alike) would take up some more time.

Comment: Does this take into account summer time or is the UTC offset fixed over the year?

Comment: It does, if you look at the function signature is takes a 'from' and a 'to' timezone as a date(time) object for when the difference is computed.  Ie for me here in Chicago in correctly determined the three weeks a year when 'your' daylight saving in Berlin is different from mine. In fact, the `example(tzDiff)` shows *exactly* that (albeit between New York and London).

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this out. It's still terribly slow on a data frame with ~500k rows. Not quite as slow as my original but still slower than molasses in January.

Comment: Thanks for going to the trouble and coming up with another solution! I suspect using `lubridate` is responsible for some of the overhead in my solution. Could probably do without but mine is already plenty fast enough that I don't much care for the additional speed gain.

Answer (score 2):

This `dplyr` + `lubridate` solution seems to work and is pretty fast:

```
df %>%
    group_by(timezone) %>%
    mutate(datetime_local = ymd_hms(datetime, tz=unique(timezone))) %>%
    mutate(datetime_utc = with_tz(datetime_local, tzone = 'UTC')) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(datetime_local) -> df
```

Note that the `datetime_local` in the resulting df is in `AEST` and may not look at all like you expect it to. I suspect this is due to the limitation in R that all elements in a `POSIXct` vector must have the same timezone. So `datetime_local` gets coerced to `AEST` on `ungroup`

Comment: See the edit I just added to my answer. Just using data.table seems to make it about five times as fast.